# Can I slow down the speed of my recorded phone calls?

Tags: applications, calls, hardware, system

I've installed the Call Recorder app on my GT-S6810P Samsung Galaxy phone. The app has successfully recorded all of my calls but when I play them back it plays them too fast. Is there any way I can slow them down?

Answer (score 1):

While the app that you installed might not have an option to change the speed of the recording, and I'm not sure why it would play it faster than the original, you can download a music player app which allows for speed change, and play your recording there.

The app that I've used is called [Music Speed Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smp.musicspeed). It's free and it allows for speed change while keeping the same pitch. When playing the recording in this app you'll see a slider for speed change adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I've tried using Music Speed Changer and I'm able to slow down the speed of my calls slightly but not enough unfortunately. Could this be because my phone is quite old or something?

Comment: That is very strange. When i slow down music using the app, it can take 20 min for a 4 min song. Make sure you move the slider all the way to the left. But if that doesn't help and you want to see if it's a problem with the phone itself, i would suggest you try playing regular music and if that's too fast, then yes something else is the problem here.